# scala switch case logic, what does otherDays mean in this code

Tags: scala

```
days match {
  case firstDay :: otherDays =>
    println("The first day of the week is: " + firstDay)
  case List() =>
    println("There don't seem to be any week days.")
}
```

In this code, what does "otherDays" mean?
How to understand this switch-case logic?

thanks

Answer (score 5):

It's not a switch per se. In Scala it's called pattern match. `days` are being matched against 2 cases in your example. Although you didn't provide the type of the `days` variable it's probably a `List`.

If your list is non-empty then it will match the first case: `case firstDay :: otherDays` and will be deconstructed or unapplied into two variables `head :: tail`. The `::` "operator" constructs a list by prepending an element on the left to the list on the right. In your case it's used to deconstruct the list. Essentially it looks like this: `::(head, tail)` which will become a call to `::.unapply(selector)` where `::` is an object and `unapply` has a signature like this:

```
def unapply[A](value: List[A]): Option[(A, List[A])]
```

So in the end `unapply` is called on your list returning `Some` of it's head and tail if the list is not empty, or `None` otherwise. Scala will convert `Option` automatically to match the right `case` in your pattern match.

Note that the result type of this expression is `Unit` and it's not very FP style. You could change it to:

```
val res =
days match {
  case firstDay :: otherDays =>
    "The first day of the week is: " + firstDay
  case List() =>
    "There don't seem to be any week days."
}
println(res)
```

to be more functional. In this case the return type will be `String` and you are delaying side effects to the very end (much more testable).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `days` is a `List` of days. The first case is a destructuring of the list, where `firstDay` is the head of the list, and `otherDays` is the tail, or "rest" of the list.

The first case will match on any non-empty list, whereas the second case will match on the empty list.